# The simplest way to check for UPPERCASES

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, validation

Here, I am trying to validate a password and check to see if there are capitals and numbers in the password before saving it as a different variable. Using functions, is it possible for me to do so. The indents have changed on the format, so please help me with other aspects.

```
def length(long):
    while len(long) < 10:
        print("Please make your password longer, up to at least 10 characters.")
        print("Your password is only " + str(len(long) + " characters long")

if password.isupper() = True:
  print("Welcome to this student interface")
  username = input("Please enter a username")
  password = input("Please enter a strong password")
  length(password)
```

This is what I have now done:

```
def length(long):
    bool LengthCheck = False
    if len(long) < 10:
        print("Please make your password longer, up to at least 10 characters.")
        print("Your password is only " + str(len(long) + " characters long")
    else:
        LengthCheck = True

errors = []

print("Welcome to this student interface")
username = input("Please enter a username")
password = input("Please enter a strong password")
length(password)

bool Capcheck = False
bool DigCheck  = False

while CapCheck = False or CapCheck = False:
    length(password)

    if not any(x.isupper() for x in password):
        errors.append("Your password needs at least 1 capital.")
    else:
        CapCheck = True
        break

    if not any(x.islower() for x in password):
        errors.append("......... Why?")

    if not any(x.isdigit() for x in password):
        errors.append("You need to have at least 1 digit")
    else:
        DigCheck = True
        break

    if errors:
        print(" ".join(errors))
        password = input("Please enter a stronger password")
```

Apparently there is an error with my boolean here, please help

```
def length(long):
    bool LengthCheck = False
    if len(long) < 10:
        print("Please make your password longer, up to at least 10 characters.")
        print("Your password is only " + str(len(long) + " characters long")
    else:
        LengthCheck = True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `islower()`:

```
password.islower()
```

This returns `True` if there are no Uppercases in the password.

---

Now if you want to check if it has number i it, you have to follow @jubnvz:

```
any(i.isdigit() for i in password)
```

or a more specific way:

```
any(map(str.isdigit, password))
```

---

And for your password entries, try:

```py
while True:
    password = input(""Please enter a strong password:")
    if not any(x.isupper() for x in password):
        print("Your password needs at least 1 upper case.")
    elif not any(x.isdigit() for x in password):
        print("You need to have at least 1 digit")
    elif not any(x.islower() for x in password):
        print("Your password needs at least 1 lower case.")
    elif len(password) < 10:
        print("Please make your password longer, up to at least 10 characters.")
        print("Your password is only " + str(len(password)) + " characters long")
    else:
        break
```

If you want to and a confirm password too, try:

```py
while True:
    password = input(""Please enter a strong password:")
    if not any(x.isupper() for x in password):
        print("Your password needs at least 1 upper case.")
    elif not any(x.isdigit() for x in password):
        print("You need to have at least 1 digit")
    elif not any(x.islower() for x in password):
        print("Your password needs at least 1 lower case.")
    elif len(password) < 10:
        print("Please make your password longer, up to at least 10 characters.")
        print("Your password is only " + str(len(password)) + " characters long")
    else:
        passwordcon = input(""Please confirm your password:")
        if passwordcon == password:
            break
        else:
            print("Your passwords do not match, try again'")
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
 any([p.isupper() for p in password])
```

Comment: The advantage of doing it this way is that you can add more validation to `p`, check if it's a symbol, or reject invalid characters, etc. Otherwise, @InfinityTM's answer is simpler

Comment: I agree, @InfinityTM's answer is simpler, so please accept it.

Comment: I have taken notice and have adjusted my work. Appreciate it

Comment: Is it possible for me to ask the person to re-enter the password if it isn't suitable?

Comment: You can. You'll need to amend your code to keep prompting the user for a password, validate it. If it's valid, carry on, otherwise, prompt again. However, the scope of your question has changed. You might want to either raise a different question